# Android Lollipop - WiFi Hotspot setWifiApEnabled() get InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm using in the app

```
setWifiApEnabled()
```

from Hidden API (access by reflection). In some older phone it´s working (also with Samsung Galaxy S3, some phones with 4.4,...) but I tested it with Samsung Galaxy S5 and I get

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
...
```

I'm using similar code like there [Android 2.2 wifi hotspot API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023226/android-2-2-wifi-hotspot-api) or [How and what to set to Android WifiConfiguration.preSharedKey to connect to the WPA2 PSK WiFi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140133/how-and-what-to-set-to-android-wificonfiguration-presharedkey-to-connect-to-the) but It´s a little old code.

Do you have experience with it? What do you suggest?

P.S. it's not working also in some Android 4.4 devices (but I don't get InvocationTargetException).

Answer (score 3):

Try This.

```
ConnectivityManager cman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Method[] methods = cman.getClass().getMethods();

        try
        {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            Method enableWifi = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            String ssid  =   " " //your SSID 
            String pass  =   " " // your Password
            WifiConfiguration  myConfig =  new WifiConfiguration();
            myConfig.SSID = ssid;
            myConfig.preSharedKey  = pass ;
            myConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            myConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            myConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            myConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            myConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP); 
            myConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP); 
            myConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
            myConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            result = (Boolean) enableWifi.invoke(wifiManager, myConfig, true);

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }
```

**In case of your exception try add this permission to your Manifest
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS**

Answer (score 3):

**You need to add these permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Added `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` to the manifest file and it worked. Try this.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setWiFiApMode(boolean mode) {
        if (mContext == null) return;
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifiManager == null) return;
        try {
            Method setWifiApEnabled = WifiManager.class.getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            setWifiApEnabled.invoke(wifiManager, null, mode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Fully works on Android N.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10260 nor current process has android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL.
```

Info:

[How can system app located in /system/app have system permission in Android 4.4 KitKat build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812924/how-can-system-app-located-in-system-app-have-system-permission-in-android-4-4)

It´s a little big problem :)